# How can I break a long ruby hash into multi-lines?

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec

I have this hash:

```
  arr={ [0,1]=>[0,0,1,1], [0,2]=>[0,1,0,1], [0,3]=>[0,1,1,0], [1,2]=>[1,0,0,1], [1,3] =>[1,0,1,0], [2,3] => [1,1,0,0] }
```

and I want split it over two lines as it is quite long, at 121 characters.  I'm not a sticker for line length but my guide line is 80 and this longer than I prefer

so I tried

```
  arr={ [0,1] => [0,0,1,1], [0,2] => [0,1,0,1], [0,3] => [0,1,1,0] }
  arr.merge({[1,2] => [1,0,0,1], [1,3] => [1,0,1,0], [2,3] => [1,1,0,0]})
```

but my tests fail with that with errors like

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I better break this up?  One option is line continuation `\` but that didn't look particularly neat.

```
arr={ [0,1]=>[0,0,1,1], [0,2]=>[0,1,0,1], [0,3]=>[0,1,1,0], \
[1,2]=>[1,0,0,1], [1,3] =>[1,0,1,0], [2,3] => [1,1,0,0] }
```

although I guess I could do

```
arr={ [0,1]=>[0,0,1,1], [0,2]=>[0,1,0,1], [0,3]=>[0,1,1,0], \
      [1,2]=>[1,0,0,1], [1,3] =>[1,0,1,0], [2,3] => [1,1,0,0] }
```

but that looks like w whitespace maintenance smell for indentation.

Are there neater options?

Comment: ... You don't need line continuation here, just end the line with a comma.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
arr = {
  [0,1] => [0,0,1,1], [0,2] => [0,1,0,1], [0,3] => [0,1,1,0],
  [1,2] => [1,0,0,1], [1,3] => [1,0,1,0], [2,3] => [1,1,0,0]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer to write it like this:

```
arr = { 
  [0,1] => [0,0,1,1],
  [0,2] => [0,1,0,1],
  [0,3] => [0,1,1,0],
  [1,2] => [1,0,0,1],
  [1,3] => [1,0,1,0],
  [2,3] => [1,1,0,0] 
}
```

It is much more readable. Also I am assume you are aware of consequences of using arrays for keys?

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt to `merge` failed, since `#merge` does not change the object you call it on, but it rather returns a new merged object. For it to work you need to use [`#merge!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21):

```
arr={ [0,1] => [0,0,1,1], [0,2] => [0,1,0,1], [0,3] => [0,1,1,0] }
arr.merge!([1,2] => [1,0,0,1], [1,3] => [1,0,1,0], [2,3] => [1,1,0,0])
```

It is quite an overkill, though, as multi-lining a hash is very easy, as stated in the other answers.